# android,not able to play some videos from urls?

Tags: android

I have 5 videos(from server) .
Here is the result for that.

Motorola Milestone 2.1update:
I am able to play only one video.
In other three videos i am able to play only audio(video can't be seen).
In one i am getting "sorry,this video cannot be played"

Galaxy tab 10.1 3.1 honeycomb:
Able to play 4 videos.
In one i am getting "sorry,this video cannot be played"

so i have simply download that video that cannot be played.Below is the results for both.
Motorola milestone 2.1update:-can hear audio but not able to see video
Galaxy tab 10.1 3.1 honeycomb:-not able to play at all.But here one interesting thing this that if i copy this(.mp4) video to sdcard it ask me [image]

No if i select yes it converts the video to wmv and i can play this video.But if i select no then get the error "Sorry,this video cannot be played."

can anybody give me clue what could be problem?if there is a problem with video(i am able to play all these videos with my pc(browser))?

Answer (score 1):

Phones cannot play all formats of video. MP4 is just a wrapper for a range of different video formats. The "Convert" option is converting your video into a format the phone can understand.

Comment: @Hitendra - Sorry, I meant to say MP4. Basically the problem is that your phone simply can't play the particular video format you gave it. Phones ship with a limited set of codecs, so they can't decode everything a PC can. Usually the reason is licensing, because they have to pay to ship each separate codec.

Comment: According to a quick Google search, your Galaxy Tab 10.1 supports:  WMV9, WMV7, WMV8, H.264, MPEG4, Xvid, DivX, H.263, and VP8.